# How to configure the filter chain programmatically?

Tags: jakarta-ee, shiro, java-ee-7

Is there a way to do programmatic restriction of  `user` access to a particular `[URL]` based on the said `users` `role`.

 
For example in a `shiro.ini` file you could define :

```
      [urls]
      ...
  1.  /app/**= user
```

which can be achieved in code be defining a `filter chain` as so:

```
 .....

 UserFilter user = new UserFilter();//create user filter
 user.setLoginUrl("login.xhtml");


FilterChainManager fcMan = new DefaultFilterChainManager();
fcMan.addFilter("user", user);//add filter to filter chain
fcMan.createChain("/app/**", "user");//define url path expression for filterName

.....
```

My question here is how do I achieve that with `roles` as i would have done in a `shiro.ini` file as so :

```
[urls]
...
/api/admin/**= user, roles[admin]
...
```

for example:

```
RolesAuthorizationFilter adminRole = new RolesAuthorizationFilter();//eg create role filter      
adminRole.setLoginUrl("login.xhtml");
UserFilter user = new UserFilter();//create user filter
user.setLoginUrl("login.xhtml");


FilterChainManager fcMan = new DefaultFilterChainManager();

fcMan.addFilter("user", user);
fcMan.addFilter("admin", adminRole);      
fcMan.createChain("/api/admin/**", "admin");
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow completely, are you looking to check the access directly against the current Subject?  i.e. subject.hasRole("ADMIN")
https://shiro.apache.org/subject.html  Or are you trying to configure the filter chain programmatically, If so which framework are you using, there might already be an easier way (Spring, Guice, etc?)

Comment: i am trying to configure the filter chain programmatically, and i am using javaee7

Comment: @Brain I accepted an asswer, and after going through the documentation for `filterChainManager#createChain` i have gotten the grabs of it. Thanks for your interest in helping out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am the author of the book "**Pairing Apache Shiro and Java EE 7**" which you can grab for free [here](https://www.infoq.com/minibooks/apache-shiro-ee-7).

[image]

In this book, I wrote all the Shiro components programmatically, without any need for the *shiro.ini* file.

I used CDI events to produce a **FilterChainResolver**:

```
@Produces
public FilterChainResolver getFilterChainResolver() {
    FilterChainResolver filterChainResolver = null;
    if (filterChainResolver == null) {
        FormAuthenticationFilter authc = new FormAuthenticationFilter();
        AnonymousFilter anon = new AnonymousFilter();
        UserFilter user = new UserFilter();

        authc.setLoginUrl(WebPages.LOGIN_URL);
        user.setLoginUrl(WebPages.LOGIN_URL);

        FilterChainManager fcMan = new DefaultFilterChainManager();
        fcMan.addFilter("authc", authc);
        fcMan.addFilter("anon", anon);
        fcMan.addFilter("user", user);

        fcMan.createChain("/index.html", "anon");
        fcMan.createChain("/css/**", "anon");
        fcMan.createChain("/api/**", "anon");
        fcMan.createChain(WebPages.LOGIN_URL, "authc");
        fcMan.createChain("/**", "user");

        PathMatchingFilterChainResolver resolver = new PathMatchingFilterChainResolver();
        resolver.setFilterChainManager(fcMan);
        filterChainResolver = resolver;
    }
    return filterChainResolver;
}
```

Next, we inject the **FilterChainResolver** in :

```
@WebListener
public class ShiroListener extends EnvironmentLoaderListener {

    @Inject
    WebSecurityManager securityManager;

    @Inject
    FilterChainResolver filterChainResolver;

    @Override
    protected WebEnvironment createEnvironment(ServletContext sc) {
        DefaultWebEnvironment webEnvironment = (DefaultWebEnvironment) super.createEnvironment(sc);

        webEnvironment.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
        webEnvironment.setFilterChainResolver(filterChainResolver);

        return webEnvironment;
    }
    ...
}
```

Now, the FilterChainResolver is applied, and everything will go as wanted.

Comment: Thank You Sir, you saved my life :D

Comment: I am happy for you @Kaizen ;-)